# Joint host and guest access to second hard disk sometimes deletes files

Tags: virtualbox

With a Windows VirtualBox guest inside an Ubuntu 18.04 host, plus a secondary hard drive (/dev/sdb) with two partitions, it seems that, by allowing both guest and host to access /dev/sbd2, I sometimes make the mistake of mounting it on the host side during a guest session and changing something. When I do, several files may be deleted from /dev/sbd2. Sometimes I can recover them by running `chkdsk` on the Windows guest or `testdisk` on Ubuntu, but sometimes some files are simply obliterated.
How could I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What files are being deleted?

Comment: I only keep my own files in there, so it’s basically pictures, documents and music score editing files (.sib from Sibelius), but I suspect they’re files in the particular folder I’d been working from (I say “I suspect” because I don’t notice the loss until days or weeks later). The last ones to disappear completely were some .doc and .rtf files in a folder I had indeed been working from. • This secondary hard drive is all NTFS.

Comment: There is nothing in Ubuntu that would do that.

Comment: Couldn’t I allow Ubuntu access to a hard drive ONLY from root or through sudo?